# Remove a string from certain column values and then operate them Pandas

Tags: pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe with a column named months (as bellow), but it contains some vales passed as "x years". So I want to remove the word "years" and multiplicate them for 12 so all column is consistent.

```
index  months
1        5
2        7
3        3 years
3        9 
4        10 years
```

I tried with

```
if df['months'].str.contains("years")==True:
  
   df['df'].str.rstrip('years').astype(float) * 12
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a multiplier series based on index with "years" and multiply those months by 12

```
multiplier = np.where(df['months'].str.contains('years'), 12,1)
df['months'] = df['months'].str.replace('years','').astype(int)*multiplier
```

You get

```
    index   months
0   1       5
1   2       7
2   3       36
3   3       9
4   4       120
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice and then use replace()

```
indexs = df['months'].str.contains("years")
df.loc[indexs , 'months'] = df['a'].str.replace("years" , "").astype(float) * 12
```

Comment: That multiplies all the column by 12. I need only years values to be multiplied

Comment: @jimmy ill edit please note i followed your example as float if you want int values change as value to int

Comment: @jimmy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.